# Отправка email без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день. Тема уже избитая, но я все равно туплю.

По заголовку вроде все понятно.

Имеется такой Html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="askform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Имя</td><td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович" required pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё ]+$"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E-mail</td><td><input name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required type="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Вопрос</td><td><textarea type="text" name="question" placeholder="Опишите, что Вас интересует" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="doask" type="submit"  value="Отправить"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#askform").submit(function() {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/ask.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function() {
                alert('Успешно');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('возникла ошибка'); 
            };
            return false;
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

И, соответственно, PHP:

```
<?php
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")
    &&(isset($_POST['question'])&&$_POST['question']!="")){
        $to = 'testmail@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Вопрос';
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $question = $_POST['question'];
        $message='
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>Имя: '.$name.'</p>
                    <p>email: '.$email.'</p>
                    <p>Вопрос: '.$question.'</p>
                </body>
            </html>';
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: testmail@gmail.com\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Грусть в том, что никакого сообщения нет, и страница перезагружается.
Где у меня ошибка?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте по другому указать путь url: "./php/ask.php",

Comment: И ещё с хабра код скопировали, да не совсем идентично. Попробуйте <textarea> на <input> поменять. Иногда в этом кроется проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="askform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Имя</td><td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович" required pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё ]+$"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail</td><td><input name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required type="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Вопрос</td><td><textarea type="text" name="question" placeholder="Опишите, что Вас интересует" required></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="doask" type="submit"  value="Отправить"/>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#askform").submit(function() {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ask.php",
                data: form_data,
                success: function () {
                    alert('Успешно');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('возникла ошибка');
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Была ошибка в JavaScript в районе "return false".

С PHP все в порядке.

У меня письмо отправилось, страница не перегружалась, появилось сообщение "Успешно".

P.S. Ошибки JavaScript помогает отлаживать инструмент браузера "Инструменты разработчика".

Comment: А письмо чет не идет. это норма?

Comment: Не знаю. Смотря на чем Вы запускаете?? У меня на Denwer'е пришло в "садок".

Comment: Тоже денвер, но тишина

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что на денвере письмо не пришло в "садок" по адресу: http://localhost/Tests/sendmail/index.php ??

Comment: Вспомнил!! В PHP не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки в конце.

Comment: Спасибо, я ждал письмо на мыле. ._ .

На нормальном хосте они нормально сразу же пойдут?

Comment: Думаю да, зависит от настроек сервера.

P.S. Попробуйте для разработки нормальную среду с проверкой кода, например, PhpStorm (http://jetbrains.ru/products/phpstorm/) там есть 30 дней пробного периода.

Comment: GHosT - ты просто красавчик! Такая простая и четкая реализация!!! Спасибо большое. Забрал себе в копилку, переписал под свою задачу немного (я, просто, JS не знаю толком пока).